# How do I make an if statement print text

Tags: python

I'm making this guess the number game. And it will not show the text 'Well done' if it got the right number.

```
from random import *

intRand = int(randint(1,5))
intTry = int(input("Pick a random number between 1 and 5\n"))

while intTry != intRand:
    if intTry == intRand:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        intTry = int(input("Try again\n"))
```

Comment: Your `while` and `if` conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: Side-notes: 1) Read [PEP8, the Python style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) at some point; Python code should not use `mixedCase` names (so the names should be either `intrand`/`inttry` or `int_rand`/`int_try`). 2) The `int(...)` wrapping in `int(randint(1, 5))` is redundant. By definition `randint` returns an `int`, there's no need to convert it. Just use `int_rand = randint(1, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` condition means that the `if` will never be true inside the loop. Put the `print` statement after the loop.

```
while intTry != intRand:
    intTry = int(input("Try again\n"))
print("Well done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You only loop while `intTry != intRand`; meaning that if you got it right on the first guess, the "well done" text would never show up - loops don't start if their condition is not met.

If you got it wrong the first time, but right after that, the "well done" text still wouldn't appear, since the loop wouldn't start again once the `intTry != intRand` condition is no longer met - because loops don't restart when their condition is not met.

To solve this, you can just move the "well done" print outside of the loop, so that the loop only happens when the number guess is not correct:

```
from random import *

intRand = int(randint(1,5))
intTry = int(input("Pick a random number between 1 and 5\n"))

while intTry != intRand:
    intTry = int(input("Try again\n"))

print("Well done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You set up the while loop incorrectly

```
from random import *

intRand = int(randint(1,5))
intTry = int(input("Pick a random number between 1 and 5\n"))


while intTry != intRand:
    intTry = int(input("Try again\n"))

print("Well done")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guessed the correct number the loop breaks and won't go in the if statement. The easiest fix would be putting "Well Done" outside of the loop, because you don't leave the loop until the number is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest technique to achieve your aim.**

> ```
> from random import *
>
> intRand = int(randint(1,5))
> intTry = int(input("Pick a random number between 1 and 5\n"))
>
> while intTry != intRand:
>     intTry = int(input("Try again\n"))
>
> #Puttng the print statement after the loop.
> print("Well done")
> ```